# Can't Access the Second Form Label

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have two windows forms called `Form1` and `Form2`. In `Form2`'s `label1` control I am trying to pass value between two Forms by using a code like this:

```
Form2 frm = new Form2();
frm.label1.Text();
frm.ShowDialog();
```

But I am getting this error message:

> 'Form2.label1' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Can you please let me know why this is happening?

Comment: because its protection level is too high - (label1 is probably private) (and also Text is a property not a method)

Comment: Hi Sayse, Thanks for comment But how I can make a control public!

Comment: Take your pick - https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=how+to+make+control+public+c%23&aq=f&oq=how+to+make+control+public+c%23&aqs=chrome.0.57j0l2j62l3.8180j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: `Text` is a property not a method, so you use it without parentheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The accessibility level of the label is too high. You can only access it if it's public, i assume it's protected.

Have a look at [**Access Modifiers**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx).

I would provide a public property in the form that maps to the label's Text. That's more readable and safer than direct  access to the control.

```
public string LabelText
{
    get {
        return label1.Text;
    }
    set {
        label1.Text = value;
    }
}
```

Now you can get/set the label's text via this property:

```
Form2 frm = new Form2();
frm.LabelText = "Hello World";
frm.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 3):

`Labell` will be declared as `protected` or `private` which means that it's not visible to other classes.

As it's autogenerated you shouldn't really change it's declaration to `public` so you'll have to either use a property to set the value or create a second constructor to pass in the new value for the label.

To use a property:

```
public string LabelValue
{
    get { return this.label1.Text; }
    set { this.label1.Text = value; }
}
```

Then:

```
Form2 frm = new Form2();
frm.LabelValue = "new string";
frm.ShowDialog();
```

To use a new constructor:

```
public Form2(string labelValue) : this()
{
    this.Label1.Text = labelValue;
}
```

Then to use it:

```
Form2 frm = new Form2("new string");
frm.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 2):

Select label1 in Form2.  Next, in the Properties Pane (bottom right by default), change the **Modifiers()** property to Public.
[image: Modifiers() Property]

Now you can do:

```
frm.label1.Text = "Hello World!";
```

This isn't considered the "correct" approach in C#, though, or in Object Oriented Programming in general.  See the other answers for how to wrap the label in a property, or pass the value to the Forms constructor.

On a side note, controls default to Public in the VB.Net IDE so you could access the Text property of the control "out of the box" as you'd expect, without needing to change anything.  Just one of the many little differences between C# and VB.Net...